# How can I add HTML tags into menu title?

Tags: 8, navigation

How can I add HTML tags into menu title?

I'm also tryed the following code.

```
function adminimal_theme_preprocess_menu(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['menu_name'] === 'main') {
    $vars['items']['standard.front_page']['title']='<i class="icon-home"></i>';
  }
}
```

It also converts tags into HTML entities.

Comment: Have you tried overriding the template files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell drupal that the string is safe. When you use `t()` this is done  automatically. But this would make no sense here, because there is nothing to translate.

In this case you can use an untranslatable markup:

```
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

function adminimal_theme_preprocess_menu(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['menu_name'] === 'main') {
    if (isset($vars['items']['standard.front_page'])) {
      $vars['items']['standard.front_page']['title'] = Markup::create('<i class="icon-home"></i>');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I try to write this: `foreach ($vars['items'] as $menu) {$menu['title'] = Markup::create($menu['title']);} ` but there is no result

Comment: But your code works

Comment: That the loop doesn't work, is not a drupal problem, this is php specific: You need a `&` before the loop variable, if you want to modify it: `foreach ($vars['items'] as &$menu)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use supporting modules for this task. please check the following:

> https://www.drupal.org/project/menuimage
>
> https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_icons

Hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: I know about these modules, but I need a solution for Drupal 8 (they for Drupal 7)

Comment: Already replied by @4k4, That's the perfect answer.