# Insert custom html into menu

Tags: 8, blocks, hooks, navigation

I am trying to insert the languageswitcher block and login block into the menu. So basically I am after inserting custom html into menu or change the html of a menu link.

Looks like the best place to do this is `hook_preprocess_menu()`. A dirty workaround is adding it under a desired menu item by finding that item with a condition check.

But there should be a more "Drupal way" of doing it. In Drupal 7, AFAIR, I could set the whole html of a menu item. But as you can see in the following `kint()` output, I couldn't find room to do that.

[image]

Here is my workaround:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_menu(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['menu_name']) && $variables['menu_name'] == 'main') {
    foreach ($variables['items'] as &$item) {
      $attributes = $item['url']->getOption('attributes');
      if (isset($attributes['class']) && in_array('locale', $attributes['class'])) {
        if ($block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('languageswitcher')) {
          $copy = $item;
          $item['is_expanded'] = true;
          $copy['locale'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
            ->getViewBuilder('block')
            ->view($block);
          $item['below'][] = $copy;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The condition I check here is a class I added with the [menu_link_attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_link_attributes) module.

Then I print it in `menu--main.html.twig`. I am using a Bootsrap submenu and putting here the whole code for reference:

```
{% import _self as menus %}

{#
  We call a macro which calls itself to render the full tree.
  @see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html
#}
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}

{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    {% if menu_level == 0 %}
      <ul{{ attributes.addClass('menu', 'nav', 'navbar-nav') }}>
    {% else %}
      <ul{{ attributes.addClass('dropdown-menu') }}>
    {% endif %}
    {% for item in items %}
      {%
        set item_classes = [
          item.is_expanded? 'expanded',
          item.is_expanded and menu_level == 0 ? 'dropdown',
          item.in_active_trail ? 'active',
        ]
      %}
      {% if menu_level == 0 and item.is_expanded %}
        <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(item_classes) }}>
        <a href="{{ item.url }}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ item.title }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
      {% elseif item.locale %}
        {{ item.locale }}
      {% else %}
        <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(item_classes) }}>
        {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
      {% endif %}
      {% if item.below %}
        {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes.removeClass('nav', 'navbar-nav'), menu_level + 1) }}
      {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

So the actual question is, what is the Drupal way of doing this?

Comment: How does your menu item looks like, This is an <p>Example</p>. Something like this? What is your input and your expectation?

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra: By design the additonal html parts look like they are part of the menu. If you click on menu item Locale, you get to switch to other languages.

Comment: Can you check whether this is what you're looking for http://drupalyourselves.blogspot.in/2017/03/include-html-tags-in-link-function-in.html

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra: Link is a workaround for this question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215826/how-can-i-add-html-tags-into-menu-title/215833