# How to add a span before my menu title link

Tags: theming, navigation

This is the default Drupal menu:

```
<ul>
  <li class="menu-item parent"><a href="" title="">0.0 Bla</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item parent"><a href="" title="">0.1 Bla</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item parent">
    <a href="" title="">1. Bla</a>
      <ul class="subnav">
       <li class="below"><a href="" title="">1. Bla</a></li>
       <li class="below"><a href="" title="">2. Bla</a></li>
       <li class="below"><a href="" title="">3. Bla</a></li>
       <li class="below">
          <a href="" title="">4. Bla</a>
           <ul class="subnav-subnav">
              <li class="below"><a href="" title="">4-1. Bla</a></li>
              <li class="below"><a href="" title="">4-2. Bla</a></li>
              <li class="below"><a href="" title="">4-3. Bla</a></li>
           </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

How to add a span after my menu link 
For example

```
<ul>
   <li class="menu-item parent"><a href="" title=""><span class="red"></span> 0.0 Bla</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item parent"><a href="" title=""><span class="red"></span> 0.1 Bla</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item parent"><a href="" title=""><span class="red"></span> 1. Bla</a>
      <ul class="subnav">
       <li class="below"><a href="" title=""><span class="blue"></span> 1. Bla</a></li>
       <li class="below"><a href="" title=""><span class="blue"></span> 2. Bla</a></li>
       <li class="below"><a href="" title=""><span class="blue"></span> 3. Bla</a></li>
       <li class="below">
          <a href="" title="">4. Bla</a>
           <ul class="subnav-subnav">
              <li class="below-below"><a href="" title=""><span class="black"></span> 4-1. Bla</a></li>
              <li class="below-below"><a href="" title=""><span class="black"></span> 4-2. Bla</a></li>
              <li class="below-below"><a href="" title=""><span class="black"></span> 4-3. Bla</a></li>
           </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Mihail, probably it's duplicate of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215826/how-can-i-add-html-tags-into-menu-title